# Check difference between stored file and file accessed by URL

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to Swift programming, and trying to sort out in my head (and my code) the best practice for the following situation:

My app accesses data from a simple txt file (merely 2KB) on a server when it loads. I'd prefer to not bundle this file with my app so I can edit the data as needed without requiring the user to update the app each time this data source is refreshed.

Further, I'd prefer my app did not require access to this file on its server each time it loads. Therefore, I'd like the app to, upon the very first time it is opened, access the file (I have this function working) and then store the data file on the phone, thus not requiring an Internet connection upon each launch.

The issue I can't solve (and extensive Googling hasn't provide much insight for) is how I could check when my app launches if its stored data file is different in comparison to the one located on the server. Then, if different, it could download and replace the data on the phone with the most recent data file.

I'm looking at using the Core Data API for storing the txt file locally. Any help advice or other questions that may have answered this I didn't locate are appreciated.

**>>>UPDATE (02/06/16) <<<**

Here is the solution that I've ended up with, in pseudocode (or my version of pseudocode...). If anyone is interested in my actual solution, I'd be more than willing to share.

```
identify name of file on phone AS phoneFile

if phoneFile does NOT exist
    create phoneFile
    retrieveData online and overwrite phoneFile with onlineData
else 
    immediately loadData from phoneFile (allowing app to be functional)
    dispatch asynchronous function (in background while data loads from phoneFile)
    {
        if phoneFile != onlineData
            update phoneFile, overwriting with onlineData
            prompt user requesting to refresh data in application
        else
            do nothing
     }
```

Hopefully that makes sense. Essentially, the first time we open the app there is no file on the phone, so we wait for the download and then run app with that data.

Each subsequent time however, we open the app with the data on the phone, and in the background check if there is new data online. My file online is only 1KB so there is not a significant download, but this method helps prevent slow app loading if the network connection is slow or interrupted.

Also, I mentioned this in comments below, but I utilized file save functions found on this tutorial here: [learncoredata.com/how-to-save-files-to-disk](http://learncoredata.com/how-to-save-files-to-disk)

Comment: You can use the `If-Modified-Since` http header if your server supports it.

Comment: For the time being, I'm simply hosting my file on Dropbox. From what I can tell Dropbox supports `If-Modified-Since` but I'm not sure how to utilize it in my Swift code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if you have two files

```
let root = NSBundle.mainBundle().resourceURL!
let localURL = root.URLByAppendingPathComponent("LocalFile")
let remoteURL = NSURL(string: "RemoteFile")

let localString = try! String(contentsOfURL: localURL)
let remoteString = try! String(contentsOfURL: remoteURL)

if(localString == remoteString) {
    They are the same
} else {
    Get the remote one and write it in.
}
```

Hope that works for you!

Comment: There's not much point storing the file locally if you're just going to download the remote one every time

Comment: Check only when connection is available, otherwise keep current?

Comment: I have implemented your suggestion for string comparison, with help from the following tutorial for data saving and loading here: http://www.learncoredata.com/how-to-save-files-to-disk/

However, @dan makes a good point, and the next problem I need to solve. How can I be sure I don't download the remote file if I don't need to update my local one?

Comment: One solution is to have a smaller file that has the version of the larger file (simply number or date modified). Check the small file for changes. If there are changes than download both the small and large file. I can help come up with another solution if this isn't fitting for you.